# Python - Difference between urllib2 and urllib

Tags: python

I am using `urllib2` with python2.7 and `urllib` with Python3.4

I am able to do what I wasnt in python2.7 which is.

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> import json
>>> result = urllib2.urlopen('http://17.2.21.7:8080/api/json')
>>> type(result)
<type 'instance'>
>>> result = json.load(result)["jobs"]
<type 'list'>
```

Now I want to do the same in Python3.4

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> result = urllib.request.urlopen('http://17.2.21.7:8080/api/json')
>>> type(result)
<class 'http.client.HTTPResponse'>
>>> result = result.read()
>>> type(result)
<class 'bytes'>
```

I need my `result` in `list` type like I am getting it using python2.7. What are the extra steps Im missing while using the `urllib` module in python3.4 ?

Comment: You removed the call to json.load

Comment: You might want to get [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), a much nicer web request library.

Comment: @JoshLee I was stuck with different types of data being returned after `urlopen` commands so I didnt even move to the step for json.load. Even when I do it, I get an ERROR. `>>> result = json.load(result)["jobs"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 312, in loads
    s.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'bytes'
`

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. Got the job done. I posted the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.6 you can call `json.loads` on a `bytes` object.

Comment: Good to know but unfortunately Im stuck with Python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to do something like this.

```
>>> import json
>>> import requests
>>> result = requests.get('http://17.2.21.7:8080/api/json')
>>> text_format = result.text
>>> json_format = json.loads(text_format)
>>> final = json_format['jobs']
```

This works.

Comment: There's also `result.json()`, which simplifies this further (and I think has some additional smart encoding detection).